# How do I make the log for J rolling files end in .log rather than .log.date

Tags: log4j

I want to change the appender pattern for the log4J logging so that the exported files end with a .log extension rather than.log.[Date] as its easier to get windows to open the file.  e.g.

I want files named like this

```
name.log
name.2016-01-26.log
name.2016-01-27.log
```

Instead of this

```
name.log
name.log.2016-01-26
name.log.2016-01-27
```

Current configuration for the appender

```
<log4j:configuration>
    <appender name="rollingfile" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="../logs/name.log"/>
        <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>
        <param name="Append" value="true"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d] %-5p [%t] %c{1} - %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which version of log4j you are using. Anyway regardless which version, you can always write your own Appender that extends the original one.

Take [this](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/logging/log4j/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender.java) as an example, you will see it always append the date to the end of the filename. What you can do is to extend the original class and overwrite its activateOptions method.

Alternatively, you can specify the DatePattern as '.'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'. However in this way your rolling log filename will be something like "name.log.2016-01-27.log".